# _mysql not found with maven project for robot framework

Tags: maven, robotframework, mysql-python

import MySQLdb

works fine on my machine. Now i have made maven project in D: directory and added following to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.hi-fi</groupId>
    <artifactId>robotframework-dblibrary</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also given external libraries path in my pom.xml and added MySQLdb folder from my Lib/site-packages to that path, still i am getting error

```
ImportError: no module named _mysql found
```

So, what all modules are needed for MySQLdb?